# How to organize the grid dynamically with grid-template-columns

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm trying to organize the grid dynamically in this way:
[image]

But my result turned out to be that one. Note the black stripes I highlighted it because it is precisely there that the image occupies a space that does not correspond to the size of it how can I do to solve this and my images are the same as the example above?

[image]

my code html:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="container">

        <div class="grid col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-25">
            <div class="imagem">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="Image path">
            <div class="layers">
                <a class="info test-popup-link" href="Image path">
                <img src="path magnifying glass"></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my css code:

```
    #container{
       padding-left: 0;
       padding-right: 0;
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    }

    .grid{
       width: 100%;
       padding-right: 2px;
       padding-left: 2px;
    }

    .imagem{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       margin-top: 4px;
       min-width: 0rem;
       float: left;
       overflow: hidden;
       background-color: #000;
       position: relative;
       text-align: center;
       cursor: default;
       margin-bottom: 0;
       box-shadow: none;
       border: none;
    }
    .img-responsive{
       display: block;
       max-width: 100%;
       height: auto;

    }
    .layers{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       position: absolute;
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
       top: 0;
       opacity: 0;
       transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

   .info{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -25px;
      margin-top: -25px;

   }
```

example jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3gj7acf8/

Comment: Probably `img-responsive` class against image doesn't allow it to cover the column

Comment: I think it is not because I removed it and the images are the size of the screen

Comment: Difficult to tell from the example you added. Would you be able to create a fiddle?

Comment: I'll edit my question with example jsfiddle

Comment: I think `display: grid` will require a lot of manual setup with `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` for every column. Have you seen https://masonry.desandro.com/?

Comment: Yes I already saw this plugin but did not want to use it

Comment: Here is what I meant with `display: grid` -> https://jsfiddle.net/3gj7acf8/1/ I don't know if that covers what you want to achieve. You also no longer need bootstrap classes.

Comment: No, it's not what I want